# Why does browser.runtime.getBackgroundPage() resolve to null in a page action script?

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon-webextensions

In the following code

```
browser.runtime.getBackgroundPage().then(bgp=>{
  document.querySelector("button").addEventListener("click", e=>{
    alert(bgp);
  });
});
```

`bgp` turns out to be `null`. I searched around and suggestions are most of the time for Chrome extensions, suggesting adding a `"background"` permission, which is not valid for Firefox. I also tried adding a background page explicitly, although one should be always created for me but it did not work either.

Answer (score 0):

[runtime.getBackgroundPage()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/runtime/getBackgroundPage) provides access to the background script, not an HTML document.

> This provides a convenient way for other privileged extension scripts
>   to get direct access to the background script's scope. This enables
>   them to access variables or call functions defined in that scope.
>   "Privileged script" here includes scripts running in options pages, or
>   scripts running in browser action or page action popups, but does not
>   include content scripts.

For example, the following code logs `<unavailable>` to the console.

```
browser.runtime.getBackgroundPage().then(bg => console.log(bg));
```

The window object can be seen in the debug console.

Comment: I know that and that's what I wanted, that's why the `alert` and not `console.log`. And I never even said I needed html. But it returns null anyway.

Comment: @Ivan What do you expect it to be? I tested, and if you check via debug console, you can see the window object.

Comment: I expected it to be the background page window object to be able to use its console.log, which should probably be clear from my first comment. But I keep getting null. Where in my question do you see *anything* about HTML?

Comment: @Ivan What is the result from my example code? Where are you running that code? Background page is a hidden page.